# How to simulate user typings of invalid passwords in react-testing-library?

Tags: react-testing-library, testing-library

When a real user type an invalid value, the input is invalidated and an error message is presented. This occurs without need to tab out/remove focus.

On my tests, I can reproduce this to `input type=text` and `input type=email`, but can't to `input type=password`.

```js
    test.each([
        ['Email','@invalid'],
        ['Senha',faker.string.sample({min: 1, max: 7})],
    ])('input [ %s ] should be invalid and show errorMessage when filled with invalid value %s', async (key: string, value) => {
        const user = userEvent.setup();
        render(<LoginPage />, {wrapper: AllTheProviders});

        const input = screen.getByLabelText(key);
        await user.type(input, parseToKeyboard(value));
        await user.tab(); 

        expect(input).toBeInvalid();
        expect(input).toHaveErrorMessage('Constraints not satisfied');
    });
```

Also tried

```js
fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: '1234567'}});
fireEvent.blur(input);
```